# jqPlot - bar chart - always color only highest value

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a page that has a bar chart that updates when a user clicks on table rows from a data table that is updated via ajax calls.

EG: the plot data is not fixed.

I need to always color the largest value / highest bar, in orange. Obviously, the highest bar could be any one of the bars in the plot.

How is this possible to do, in an efficient way with jqplot?

I have seen examples with bars colored in various series colors, but I need one color only, with all bars being blue except for the largest value, which needs to be orange.

I cant see any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution to this and got this working. It isn't very elegant, but it works!

The bar colours are just an array, so how I did this was to...

1) Colour all bars the same

```
 var colorArray = ['#4bb2c5','#4bb2c5','#4bb2c5','#4bb2c5','#4bb2c5','#4bb2c5','#4bb2c5'];
```

2) Find the max data value

```
 var maxValue = Math.max(data01,data02,data03,data04,data05,data06,data07);
```

3) Change the colour array value if the data is the maximum value

```
if (data01 == maxValue) { colorArray[0] = '#fbbc05'; }
else if (data02 == maxValue) { colorArray[1] = '#fbbc05'; }
else if (data03 == maxValue) { colorArray[2] = '#fbbc05'; }
else if (data04 == maxValue) { colorArray[3] = '#fbbc05'; }
else if (data05 == maxValue) { colorArray[4] = '#fbbc05'; }
else if (data06 == maxValue) { colorArray[5] = '#fbbc05'; }
else if (data07 == maxValue) { colorArray[6] = '#fbbc05'; }
```

4) Set up the bar chart plot

```
var bar_options = {
 axesDefaults: { labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer },
 seriesColors: colorArray,
 seriesDefaults: { renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer, rendererOptions: { highlightMouseOver:false, barMargin:5, shadowOffset:1, varyBarColor:true } },
 axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer } }
 };
```

And it works!

Hope this helps someone else!